# Tell the Rust compiler that the lifetime of a parameter is always identical to a struct's lifetime

Tags: rust

Sorry if this is obvious, I'm starting out with Rust.

I'm trying to implement a simple Composition relationship (one object is the single owner of another one, and the inner object is destroyed automatically when the outer object dies).

I originally thought it would be as simple as declaring a struct like this:

```rust
struct Outer {
    inner: Inner
}
```

To my knowledge, that does exactly what I want: the inner attribute is owned by the outer struct, and will be destroyed whenever the outer object disappears.

However, in my case, the `Inner` type is from a library, and has a lifetime parameter.

```rust
// This is illegal
struct Outer {
    inner: Inner<'a>
}

// I understand why, I'm using an undeclared lifetime parameter
```

I have read a bit on lifetime parameters (but I'm not yet completely used to them), and I'm unsure whether there is some syntax to tell the Rust compiler that “the lifetime this field expects is its owner's“, or whether it's just not possible (in which case, what would be the proper way to architecture this code?).

## Edit: more detailed situation

I'm writing a project with Vulkano. I want to bundle multiple structures into a single structure so I can pass all at once to functions throughout the project.

Here, I have:

- The `Engine` struct, which should hold everything
- The `Instance` struct, which represents the Vulkan API
- The `PhysicalDevice` struct, which represents a specific GPU, and can only be used as long as its matching `Instance` exists

The struct I'm struggling with is `PhysicalDevice`:

```rust
// https://github.com/vulkano-rs/vulkano/blob/c6959aa961c9c4bac59f53c99e73620b458d8d82/vulkano/src/device/physical.rs#L297
pub struct PhysicalDevice<'a> {
    instance: &'a Arc<Instance>,
    device: usize,
}
```

I want to create a struct that looks like:

```rust
pub struct Engine {
    instance: Arc<Instance>,
    device: PhysicalDevice,
}
```

Because the `Engine` struct owns `PhysicalDevice` as well as `Arc<Instance>`, and the instance referenced by `PhysicalDevice` is the same as the one referenced by the `Engine`, the `PhysicalDevice`'s lifetime requirement should always be valid (since the contained instance cannot be freed before the `Engine` is freed).

I don't have very good reason of using this architecture, apart from the fact that this is the standard way of bundling related data in other languages. If this not proper "good practices" in Rust, I'm curious as to what the recommended approach would be.

Comment: Basically two possibilities: bubble up the lifetime with `struct Outer<'a> {…}` or use `'static`. Which is the correct option depends on your use case.

Comment: *To my knowledge, that does exactly what I want: the inner attribute is owned by the outer struct, and will be destroyed whenever the outer object disappears.* - This is incomplete. The trouble is that `inner` may contain references to something on the caller's stack, i.e. something _not_ accounted-for by `Outer`. This is why the lifetime needs to be propagated to `Outer`, or you need to use `static`, which just means that no such references are allowed (or they must point to global data).

Comment: `&'a Arc<Instance>` doesn't make sense, you should use a straight `Arc<Instance>`.

Comment: That's library code, not mine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> “the lifetime this field expects is its owner's“,

This is impossible.

Generally, you should understand any type with a lifetime parameter (whether it is a reference `&'a T` or a struct `Foo<'a>` or anything else) as pointing to *something elsewhere and which lives independently.*

In your case, whatever `Inner` borrows (whatever its lifetime is about) *cannot* be a part of `Outer`. This is because if it was, `Outer` would be borrowing parts of itself, which makes `Outer` impossible to use normally. (Doing so requires *pinning*, preventing the struct from moving and thereby invalidating the references, which is not currently possible to set up without resorting to `unsafe` code.)

So, there are three cases you might have:

1. Your full situation is

   ```rust
   struct Outer {
       some_data: SomeOtherType,
       inner: Inner<'I_want_to_borrow_the_some_data_field>,
   }
   ```

   This is not possible in basic Rust; you need to either

   - put `some_data` somewhere other than `Outer`,
   - use the [`ouroboros`](https://docs.rs/ouroboros/) library which provides mechanisms to build sound self-referential structs (at the price of heap allocations and a complex interface),

   or design your data structures differently in some other way.
2. The data `Inner` borrows is already independent. In that case, the correct solution is to propagate the lifetime parameter.

   ```rust
   struct Outer<'a> {
       inner: Inner<'a>,
   }
   ```
3. There is not actually any borrowed data; `Inner` provides for the possibility but isn't actually using it in this case (or the borrowed data is a compile-time constant). In this case, you can use the `'static` lifetime.

   ```rust
   struct Outer {
       inner: Inner<'static>,
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm not really sure what the proper solution is. I've added more information in the question. I think I'm in case 1, but since I don't have any good reason of sticking with this design and I'm fairly new to Rust, I don't think ouroboros is a good idea for now. Any recommendations for how to organize my code better?

Comment: @CLOVIS That will depend on what you're doing. I do not know how Vulkano is supposed to be used. (Note that it's also possible that libraries can be designed badly, overusing references and making certain use cases impossible without tools like `ouroboros`.)

Comment: After asking the Vulkano team, it seems like this type is just meant to be kept as a local variable, not as a persistent data. Your answer was quite well explained, so I'm marking it as accepted. More details at https://github.com/vulkano-rs/vulkano/issues/1771

Answer (score -2):

You can use a bound on `Self`:

```
struct Outer<'a> where Self: 'a {
    inner: Inner<'a>
}
```

Comment: I can't speak for all the downvotes but it seems like it doesn't meet the OP's goal of _not having_ a lifetime parameter. All it does is additionally constrain what that lifetime can be.

Comment: Fair enough. I did not interpret the question that way, sorry! I'll keep the answer up anyways since it might be useful to someone else.